# Tornado Interceptor - Empty Response

Tags: python, tornado, interceptor

I'm using an interceptor to check the validity of a token passed by the user in my tornado application.

```
def token_authenticate():
    def wrapper(self, transforms, *args, **kwargs):
        def _throw_error(self):
            print 'writing basic auth'
            if self._headers_written:
                raise Exception('headers have already been written')
            self.write(json.dumps({'auth': 'false'}))
            self.finish()
            return False

        request = self.request
        try:
            token = request.arguments.get('token')[0]
            if not token:
                return _throw_error(self)

            session = Instance().get_session()

            user_token = session.query(UserToken)\
                .filter(UserToken.token == token)\
                .filter(UserToken.expires > datetime.utcnow())\
                .one()

            if user_token:
                self.token = user_token
                self.user = user_token.user

            else:
                print 'no user token'
                return _throw_error(self)
        except Exception, e:
            print 'exception ' + e
            return _throw_error(self)
        return True

    return wrapper

def interceptor(func):
    def classwrapper(cls):
        def wrapper(old):
            def inner(self, transforms, *args, **kwargs):
                log.debug('Invoking wrapper %s', func)
                ret = func(self, transforms, *args, **kwargs)
                if ret:
                    return old(self, transforms, *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    return ret

            return inner

        cls._execute = wrapper(cls._execute)
        return cls

    return classwrapper

## HANDLER
@interceptor(token_authenticate())
class SampleAuthenticatedRequestHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write({'response': self.user.as_dict()})
```

The request receives an empty response when the token is missing/invalid.

```
> curl localhost:8888/test -I -v
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fb18b004000
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fb18b004000) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 8888 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8888 (#0)
> HEAD /test HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:8888
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Is there something missing? Is this the best way to abstract authentication away from my handler? I was hoping to replicate this model for different kinds of authentication (token based, session based etc).

Answer (score 0):

`RequestHandler._execute` is an internal method and this will break in Tornado 4.0.  `prepare()` and the HTTP verb methods `get()`/`post()`/etc are the supported methods to be overridden in subclasses.  I don't see any reason that this code would return an empty response, although the server logs (which you did not post) might have something useful.

Comment: There are no useful logs from what I could see but I may have found the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553694/how-does-tornado-stop-current-request-handler.

I may have to move the major part of my authentication to a handler within one of the verb methods. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working version of the above function. Just for anyone else who's having the same trouble -

```
def token_authenticate():
    """
    This is a basic authentication interceptor which
    protects the desired URIs and requires
    authentication as per configuration
    """

    def wrapper(self, transforms, *args, **kwargs):

        request = self.request
        try:
            token = request.arguments.get('token')[0]
            if not token:
                return False

            user_token = get_user(token)

            if user_token:
                self.token = user_token
                self.user = user_token.user
                return True
        except:
            pass
        return False

    return wrapper


def interceptor(func):
    """
    This is a class decorator which is helpful in configuring
    one or more interceptors which are able to intercept, inspect,
    process and approve or reject further processing of the request
    """

    def classwrapper(cls):
        def wrapper(old):
            def inner(self, transforms, *args, **kwargs):
                ret = func(self, transforms, *args, **kwargs)
                if ret:
                    return old(self, transforms, *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    self._transforms = transforms
                    return self._unauthorized()

            return inner

        cls._execute = wrapper(cls._execute)
        return cls

    return classwrapper
```