# I wrote a project with tornado, but this exception is always in my log file

Tags: python, tornado

This is the error log:

> [I 160308 11:09:59 web:1908] 200 GET /admin/realtime (117.93.180.216) 107.13ms
>   [E 160308 11:09:59 http1connection:54] Uncaught exception
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 238, in _read_message
>           delegate.finish()
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 290, in finish
>           self.delegate.finish()
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1984, in finish
>           self.execute()
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/blueware-1.0.10/blueware/hooks/framework_tornado/web.py", line 480, in _bw_wrapper__RequestDispatcher_execute
>           future = wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2004, in execute
>           **self.handler_kwargs)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/blueware-1.0.10/blueware/hooks/framework_tornado/web.py", line 448, in _bw_wrapper_RequestHandler___init___
>           return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 185, in **init**
>           self.initialize(**kwargs)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2714, in wrapper
>           self.redirect(url)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 671, in redirect
>           self.finish()
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/blueware-1.0.10/blueware/hooks/framework_tornado/web.py", line 309, in _bw_wrapper_RequestHandler_finish_
>           return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 934, in finish
>           self.flush(include_footers=True)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 870, in flush 
>           for transform in self._transforms:
>       TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
>   [I 160308 11:10:00 web:1908] 200 GET /admin/order?order_type=1&order_status=1&page=0&action=allreal (49.89.27.173) 134.53ms

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem? Thank you very much

Comment: please look over [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which will improve the chances of a stack overflow user being able to understand your problem

Comment: you have to check about your `blueware-1.0.10/blueware/hooks/framework_tornado/web.py` it seems this packages tries to iterate over something that returns `None`, try to do a `try ... except TypeError doSomething....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that OneAPM (blueware agent) is compatible with your python and Tornado version, however it's can be tricky.

### Solution

Move `self.redirect(url)` from your handler `initialize` method to `get` method, like this

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.redirect('/some_url')
```

or use [RedirectHandler](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RedirectHandler).

Every action that could finish request needs to be called in context of http-verb method (get, post, put and so on). The [common mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553694/how-does-tornado-stop-current-request-handler) is making authetication/authorization in `__init__` or `initialize`.

#### More detail

In Tornado's source there is a note about `_transforms` that is initialized in the constructor with `None` and set in`_execute` (oversimplifying - after headers_received).

> A transform modifies the result of an HTTP request (e.g., GZip encoding).
>
> Applications are not expected to create their own OutputTransforms
>   or interact with them directly; the framework chooses which transforms
>   (if any) to apply.

#### Reproduce

Sample that triggers this error. I'm including this only as a cross-check that blueware is not the cause:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class SomeHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def initialize(self, *args, **kwargs):
        url = '/some'
        self.redirect(url) 
        # ^ this is wrong

    def get(self):
        # redirect should be here
        self.write("Hello")


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", SomeHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

And  stacktrace:

```
ERROR:tornado.application:Uncaught exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 238, in _read_message
    delegate.finish()
  File "/tmp/py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 289, in finish
    self.delegate.finish()
  File "/tmp/py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2022, in finish
    self.execute()
  File "/tmp/py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2042, in execute
    **self.handler_kwargs)
  File "/tmp/py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 183, in __init__
    self.initialize(**kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 8, in initialize
    self.redirect(url)
  File "/tmp/py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 666, in redirect
    self.finish()
  File "/tmp/py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 932, in finish
    self.flush(include_footers=True)
  File "/tmp/py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 868, in flush
    for transform in self._transforms:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```